# What is the degree of the extension of the field of rational functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

On page 595 of Dummit and Foote, there is an example of the field $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x,y)$ of rational functions in the variables $x$ and $y$ over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and that this is not a simple extension of the subfield $F=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x^p,y^p)$.

The authors state that "it is easy to see that $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x,y): \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p(x^p,y^p)]=p^2$. However, I am having trouble seeing why this is true. What would the basis for this extension be? Or is there an easier way to see why this is the degree?

Comment: Let $A$ be the larger field and $B$ the smaller. Too painful to type. Every element $f/g\in A$ can be written as $g^{p-1}f/g^p$ and $g^p\in B$. Therefore, every element of $A$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $B$. Now, each term of $g^{p-1}f$ is an element of $B$ times one of the monomials $x^iy^j$ with $i,j\in\{0,1,...,p-1\}$. So, those monomials generate $A$ over $B$.